# geom_function with user written function in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I will be highly grateful for your help. I am learning how to use *geom_function* in r. Following is my function:

```
x0 <- 0.5
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3

x <- c(x0, x1, x2, x3)

myfn <- function(w, b, a, x){
    w^(1-b)/(1-b)-a*w-(w>100 & w<=200)*x[3]*(w-100)-(w>200)*x[3]*100-x[4]*(w-200)
}
```

My objective is to plot above function using *geom_function* to see how this function behaves with different values of arguments *a* and *b* and following is my code:

```
y=seq(0,1000,5)

ggplot()+
  xlim(c(0,1000))+
  geom_function(fun=myfn(w=y, b=-4, a=0.5, x=x))
```

Problem: I feel my logic is correct but when I execute above code, I get nothing. I will be highly grateful for the help. Thank you very much for the help in advance. Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you have not specified `x` in your aes

Comment: @Oliver: Thank you for your suggestion. I am confused, can you elaborate please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function `myfn` is a function of `w` where `a`, `b` and `x` are parameters. To plot this function over the range of `c(0, 1000)` pass your function to the `fun` argument and the parameters as a list via the `args` argument and set the range via `xlim`:

```r
x0 <- 0.5
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3

x <- c(x0, x1, x2, x3)

myfn <- function(w, b, a, x) {
  w^(1 - b) / (1 - b) - a * w - (w > 100 & w <= 200) * x[3] * (w - 100) - (w > 200) * x[3] * 100 - x[4] * (w - 200)
}

library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 1000)) +
  geom_function(fun = myfn, args = list(b = -4, a = 0.5, x = x))
```

A second option would be to make use of a lambda function like so:

```
ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 1000)) +
  geom_function(fun = ~ myfn(.x, b = -4, a = 0.5, x = x))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I had set `w` equal to x and that did not work. I could not wrap my head around it. Does it consider `w` as y, because `w` it is left undefined?

Comment: It is a bit confusing, w is considered x in the graph, your x is just some constants and the y in the plot is the outcome of your function based on values for w.

Comment: @DionGroothof. Haha. Took me also some time to realize that `x` is not the argument but a parameter. But you are right. Under the hood `geom_function`will first create a grid according to the range. This vector is then passed to the function and will be passed to the first argument or the first unnamed argument, i.e. w. However we could also make use of a lambda function i.e. `fun = ~ myfn(w = .x, b = -4, a = 0.5, x = x)`

Answer (score 1):

```
myfn <- function(x, a, b, c) {
  x^(1 - b) / (1 - b) - a * x - (x > 100 & x <= 200) * c[3] * (x - 100) - (x > 200) * c[3] * 100 - c[4] * (x - 200) # outcome is y
}

ggplot() +
  xlim(c(0, 1000)) +
  geom_function(fun = ~ myfn(x = .x, a = 0.5, b = -4, c = c(0.5, 1, 2, 3)))
```

If you do not want to add the variables through the args list you can add the variables to your function like this. Note I changed some of the variable names to make it more clear what the actual x and y are in the plot. Also x by the OP is just a list with 4 constants, I provided them as a and b under the name c.